# Moq - Unable to Convert from x to System.Func<x>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to mock this method:

```
 public JsonSerializerSettings createSerializerSettingsUsingRequest(Request request)
        {

            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new Utilities.CustomContractResolver(false, request.text)
            };
            return serializerSettings;
        }
```

And this is how I mock:

```
 _service = new Mock<IService>();
 _service.Setup(x => x.createSerializerSettingsUsingRequest(It.IsAny<Request>()))
                                .Returns<JsonSerializerSettings>(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new Utilities.CustomContractResolver(false, null) });
```

But the error shows

> cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings' to
>   `System.Func<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings>`

Anyone knows how to mock it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the generic argument. The overload you are trying to invoke does not do what you think it does.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { 
    ContractResolver = new Utilities.CustomContractResolver(false, null) 
};
_service
    .Setup(x => x.createSerializerSettingsUsingRequest(It.IsAny<Request>()))
    .Returns(settings);
```

If you are trying to replicate the behavior of the original method then get access to the passed argument.

For example

```
_service
    .Setup(x => x.createSerializerSettingsUsingRequest(It.IsAny<Request>()))
    .Returns<Request>(request => new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        ContractResolver = new Utilities.CustomContractResolver(false, request.text) 
    });
```